# giving input to bash script from a java program

Tags: java, bash, process

I invoked a script from java program using ProcessBuilder class. The script prompts for some input. how to pass value from java program.

I tried like using that process i get a writer object and tried to write the value but it doesn't worked.

Comment: You can pass all command line arguments to the process as a list of strings. In that list, first one is your command name and rest all are your inputs to the process. is this you wanted?

Comment: yes,what you said is correct. but i need to enter input at run time only. I cant predict the input before running the script

Comment: Hopefully, first you need to read all the inputs and then start your process with the input you collected.

Comment: I already told you that i cant predict answers. In java 7 I seen something like processbuilder.redirect.pipe will it helps me..?

Answer (score 0):

If the subprocess (script) reads its input from the standard input stream, you can feed it through the connected output stream (`getOutputStream()`).